# Xen + libvirt: VM name 'Domain-Unnamed' already exists

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, libvirt

I had to restart a paravirt guest and could not start over again.

It's only the xenstore crash?

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.0.3
Using library: libvirt 1.0.3
Usando a API: Xen 1.0.3
Hypervisor em execução: Xen 4.2.0
```

CentOS 6 - x64

```
Linux eagle 3.9.8-1.el6xen.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Jun 29 16:23:39 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've got this error:

```
[07.08.2013 08:21:45 3322] INFO (XendDomainInfo: 169) Recreating domain 13, UUID 0a1ddba3-c1d7-5675-9e5d-1b79d02b5ea2. at / local/domain/13
[07.08.2013 08:21:45 3322] WARNING (XendDomainInfo: 191) / vm/0a1ddba3-c1d7-5675-9e5d-1b79d02b5ea2/uuid / is missing. recreate is confused, trying our best to recover
[07.08.2013 08:21:45 3322] ERROR (XendDomain: 447) Unable to recreate domain
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/ usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomain.py", line 445, in _refreshTxn
     new_dom XendDomainInfo.recreate = (dom, False)
   File "/ usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 204, in recreate
     vmpath = vmpath)
   File "/ usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 455, in __ init__
     self._checkName (self.info ['name_label'])
   File "/ usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 3524, in _checkName
     ("The domain% s"% str (dom.domid)) or ""))
VmError: VM name 'Domain-Unnamed' already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

I return here to tell the solution.

Simple reboot host resolve the problem. Xen recreates the scenario without errors. In my case, I had  "qemu-dm" zombie processes, too.

Another user with this problem: http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/11820/35005/

How to recovery xenstore: http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx116203

After googling I found a important tip about xenstored: **Never restart xenstored service**. It's like a linux /proc.